# How can I select an element that its value contains plus character by value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the element I need to select:

```
<select>
    <option value="CSS326-24G-2S+RM">CSS326-24G-2S+RM</potion>
</select>
```

And here is my selector code:

```
var value = "CSS326-24G-2S+RM";
$("option[value="+value+"]").val('selected');
```

But it doesn't select tat element. Since `+` has a specific meaning in jQuery selector. Anyway, how can I escape that `value` variable while using it in the `$()` selector?

```js
$(function(){
  var value = "CSS326-24G-2S+RM";
  $("option[value="+value+"]").val('the element is selected');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="CSS326-24G-2S+RM">CSS326-24G-2S+RM</potion>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method to achieve this is two simply wrap the value in the attribute selector in quotes:

```js
$(function(){
  var value = "CSS326-24G-2S+RM";
  $('option[value="' + value + '"]').val('the element is selected');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="CSS326-24G-2S+RM">CSS326-24G-2S+RM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can not reject **[my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20391498)** and then write what I have suggested.

Comment: Yeah I can, as the `See in JS section below` is redundant noise. All that was needed was to correct the `</potion>` typo